# Flatpickr: Auto-Add Delimiter when Typing Date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, user-experience, flatpickr

Is there a built-in way for Flatpickr to automatically add a delimiter when a user is manually typing a date in to the input field?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jQuery masking function for this.

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const flatpickr_time = $('#flatpickr_time').flatpickr({
    allowInput: true,
    dateFormat: 'd/m/Y'
  });

  $('#flatpickr_time').mask("99/99/9999");
  $('#flatpickr_time').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val().substring(0, 2) > 12 || $(this).val().substring(0, 2) == "00") {
      console.log("Wrong month format");
      return false;
    }
    if ($(this).val().substring(3, 5) > 31 || $(this).val().substring(0, 2) == "00") {
      console.log("Wrong date format");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.js"></script>

<input id="flatpickr_time" style="width:200px;">
```